# Exception handling using mysql with twisted adbapi and scrapy

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, scrapy, twisted

I'm using [this](https://gist.github.com/tzermias/6982723) scrapy pipeline. If there is any error in the sql in the insert_record function, it fails silently. For example, if a column name is miss-spelled, like this

```
def _insert_record(self, tx, item):
        print "before tx.execute"
        result = tx.execute(
        """ INSERT INTO table(col_one, col_typo, col_three) VALUES (1,2,3)""" 
        )
        print "after tx.execute"
        if result > 0:
            self.stats.inc_value('database/items_added')
```

then nothing is output after "*before execute*". There is a handle_error method but that's not called either. How can I catch and handle such errors?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to surround it with try...except

```
try:
    result = tx.execute(
    """INSERT INTO table(col_one, col_typo, col_three) VALUES (1,2,3)"""
    )
except Exception,e: 
    print str(e)
```